# Files mounted over NFSv4 are owned by 4294967294, UIDs and GIDs match

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs

I have two identical linux machines (identical images launched in amazon EC2) and I am trying to mount an exported directory over NFSv4. Here is what the mounted directory looks like on the client machine:

```
root@server:~# ls -l /websites/
drwxr-xr-x  6 4294967294 4294967294   92 2010-01-01 20:21 logs
drwxr-xr-x  2 4294967294 4294967294   20 2009-12-23 01:14 monit.d
...
```

I double checked to make sure that the UIDs were matching

Here is the mount command I run from the client

```
/sbin/mount.nfs4 $MASTER_DN:/ /websites -o rw,_netdev,async
```

And here is the `/etc/exports` entry on the server machine:

```
/websites 10.0.0.0/8(fsid=0,no_subtree_check,rw,no_root_squash)
```

Comment: is rpcidmapd service running? start them using commands.
/etc/init.d/rpcidmapd restart
chkconfig rpcidmapd on

Answer (score 9):

read here http://blather.michaelwlucas.com/archives/796

If the NFSv4 client and server domain names doesn’t match,all the usernames will show up as “nobody.”

1. edit /etc/idmapd.conf and set Domain on server and client to the "localdomain"

   [General]

   Domain = localdomain

   [Translation]

   Method = nsswitch
2. change the /etc/default/nfs-common file (on both your server and client): set     NEED_IDMAPD= yes
3. start idmapd service

Comment: For me this answer solved the issue I had (after "idmapd" had crashed for som ereason).

Answer (score 8):

As explained in [UID /GID with NFS and ZFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/223408/uid-gid-with-nfs-and-zfs#answer-223415),  NFSv4 doesn't use UIDs.  I was having a similar problem and was able to work around it by using NFSv3.  This just entails adding `-o vers=3` to the `mount` command.  Of course, if you do need to use NFSv4 this response won't be of much use to you.

Answer (score 7):

This is a user id mapping problem.  For some reason the system is using the "nobody" account instead of the true account ids.  Check your squashing options and your idmapd.conf file.

Here is a thread I found that discusses the problem, this links to the post of interest, http://www.mail-archive.com/rhelv5-list@redhat.com/msg03303.html.

FYI, 4294967294 is -2, if treated as a 32-bit signed integer.  -1 or -2 are used on various Linux distros for the nobody UID and nogroup GID (in the passwd file the highest 16 bit unsigned number, 65535, is generally used).

Comment: Thanks for the response, David. Per my post, I have `no_root_squash` enabled. Do you have any more info about the idmapd.conf file?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the /etc/default/nfs-common file (on **both** your server and client): set `NEED_IDMAPD` to `yes`.

At least this helped for me.

Answer (score 2):

We are using the NFS options `anonuid` and `anongid` to set the user/group IDs the server will use for files created by anonymous. If these are not set, "nobody" and "nogroup" will be used - which may vary depending on OS version and distribution. So a

```
/websites 10.0.0.0/8 
    (fsid=0,no_subtree_check,rw,no_root_squash,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001)
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

may to the trick (with 1001 being a valid and usable UID/GID on your server).