# UID /GID with NFS and ZFS

Tags: nfs, zfs

I have a server with a zfs file system (nexenta core), and I'm sharing files overs nfs with zfs share share_nfs.

When I mount the file system on my client (a ubuntu workstation) I can't have the original UID/GID :(

I mount my client with the following options : 192.168.1.4:/home /media/testnfs nfs rw,dev,noexec,nosuid,auto,nouser,noatime,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 0 0

If I configure idmapd I have  nobody:nogroup and without idmapd I have 4294967294:4294967294, how can I get the original ID's ?

Is it a problem with the nfs server or the client ?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NFSv4 doesn't use UID/GIDs anymore. There are quite a few significant differences between NFSv3 and v4; security is one of them.

Comment: Oki so maybe I can try to force use of nfs 3 to have original UID / GID.

Comment: It's working with an update of /etc/default/nfs to force use of nfs v3 version thank you :)